# How to type a per mille symbol (‰) in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, unicode

Could anyone please tell me how to type a *per mille* symbol (‰) in MATLAB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can print it on figures, using its [unicode value](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2030/index.htm)

```
figure;text(.5,.5,char(8240))
```

Or simply using `%c` in [string formatting](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/formatting-strings.html):

```
fprintf(1, '%c\n', char(8240) )
‰
```

Comment: Thank for your reply. But how can I use `unicode` when I want to print it in the `xlable` of a plot in `MATLAB`?

Comment: You simply use `char(8240)` in your `xlabel` string: `xlabel(['I want to have ', char(8240), ' symbol'])`

Comment: Or with normal printf-formatting: `xlabel(sprintf('I want to have %c', char(8240')))`

Comment: @Jørgen exactly, like the `fprintf` example.

Comment: My code is like that: `xlabel('I want to have',char(8240),'symbol.');` and it does not work. I think the "[]" is not a MATLAB expression. Could you please give me a solution in a MATLAB expression?

Comment: @eapsclimate why do you think `[]` is not a matlab expression?? have you tried it? I *already* gave you a solution - you refuse to use it!

Comment: @Shai I feel sorry about that, but the system give me a remind like that: `Error using text
Invalid parameter/value pair arguments

Error in untitled (line 41)
figure;text(char(8240))`

Comment: @eapsclimate why don't you copy-paste the code from the answer?? why are you omitting symbols and arguments? `text` command needs more arguments: `text( 0.5, 0.5, char(8240) )`

Comment: @Shai I think some of my previous codes lead to the error, your solution finally works. Thanks a lot and sorry about my carelessness.